# Combine Linux multipath iSCSI disks

Tags: linux, centos, storage, mount

I have a CentOS 7 server which is currently receiving storage via a mounted iSCSI multipath session. The multipath device which represents this block storage in `/dev/mapper` is mounted to a folder in `/mnt/x`

There is a server application running which is configurable with only one folder path to use as storage, currently pointing to `/mnt/x`

My issue is that this application uses a huge amount of storage. Currently the iSCSI LUN is 50TB and we need to expand it every few months.

I am wondering is there a way I can present multiple smaller iSCSI LUNs via multipath to this server, and somehow combine the storage so they appear as a single mountpoint `/mnt/x`?

I know there are solutions such as `mhddfs` but they all seem to work with locally attached storage, and besides I am not game enough to try these out with this volume of data. The actual solution they present would work excellent for my case though, as it can store files the application creates across multiple LUNs - avoiding a situation where if one LUN drops out the entire mount point will be unresponsive, as might be the case with `LVM`.

I want to try and avoid having one huge LUN, I can realistically see this approach 100TB in the next month or two so I want to see if I can plan ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single solution that you can casually drop LUNs from that provides a JBOD-style block device concatenation like you need. LVM is my first thought, but if you were to lose any of these many points of failure, you VG would be in a degraded state and you'd probably have data issues.

You might consider a different approach with this altogether. Right now you're expanding volumes manually to accommodate demands at presumably multiple endpoints. Why not give these endpoints large thinly provisioned volumes and move that management issue to a central location that's good at managing storage?

True, you would have to keep up with adding storage to the iSCSI target, but that's generally more graceful than endpoints and can be done when your volumes are truly low on space. I say all of this in a hopeful tone, because I don't know if you have to use some kind of horrible SAN product behind this all that won't do simple things like expand volumes online.

With that in mind, I'm curious as to what product you're actually using for your SAN, as that would be critical information in determining how you might effectively deal with this problem.

Comment: Yeah it's a tough one, may even need an overhaul in the future. This solution is for a multitenant, cloud based backup service. We are using a large FreeNAS configuration with SuperMicro servers & JBOD units (you can call this our 'SAN', however it is strictly cold storage). Expanding FreeNAS is no issue, purely the fact of the server application needing one mount point is the problem. (FreeNAS -> Server -> Multiple endpoints via proprietary protocol). I may need to introduce multiple servers and stagger the endpoints across these manually

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using CentOS, you may consider using GlusterFS.
It was supported by RedHat now and can be setup quite easily.
Check their website for more info.